# How can I map elements which Ive got from database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I want to ask you how can I map elements from database. I basically want to make something like: `(name = {name}, isOn = {isOn})`. [image]

And the code of the component which should get assigned data:

```js
const Islbutton = props => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(true);
  // some functions
  return (
    <div>
      <img src = {isOn ? islon : isloff} alt= "" onClick={() =>toggleImage()}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Instead of making `isOn` part of the state, pass it down as prop, exactly like you have in your question: `{this.state.buttons.map(btnData => <Islbutton isOn={btnData.isOn} />)}` (but never, ever, make an API call in your render function. move it to `componentDidMount` and store the result in a state variable initialized to `[]`)

Comment: I have downLayout as a parent component then > MachineWrapper which wraps the components and then > Islbutton. Wont it be a problem? (I want to pass data for all 5 components as well though)

Comment: According to your 2nd part of answer then yeah, it was just for testing and not integrating in code too much

Comment: Why would it be a problem? And don't call APIs in `render()`, even for testing.

Comment: Here's example code including processing a click in the parent: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tu-7bkr9

Comment: @ChrisG off topic, but why should an API call not be okay in a function component? Surely, `useState` will suffice?

Comment: @aabbccsmith Obviously, but I'm talking about *inside the `render()`* function.

Comment: While I follow your code it gives me the "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: That happens when a function isn't bound to the component properly. Note how I used `.bind(this)` in the `App` component to make sure it is bound properly (if the function isn't bound, `this` will be `undefined`, which causes the error you're getting when you're trying to call `this.setState`)

Comment: Yes I see but you used the .bind(this) for btnClick which I dont need for the wrapper component so I got rid of it but it yells me about that setState of { users }

Comment: Bind the function to the component in which it is defined, then pass it down. My code shows how to do this, I don't think that I can help you further, much less in the comments of an unrelated question.

Comment: @ChrisG Ahhhh, I see I see, my apologies 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `useEffect` to handle external property change in a function component. See the example below,

```js
const { Component, useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const Islbutton = props => {
  const { toggleLight } = props;
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(props.naem);
    setIsOn(props.isOn);
  });

  const islon =
    "https://cdg-webhosting.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/help-hint-icon.png";
  const isloff =
    "https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/light-bulb-on-off-png-16.vnd";

  // some functions
  return (
      <img src={isOn ? islon : isloff} alt={name} onClick={toggleLight} />
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    lights: [
      { name: "light1", isOn: true },
      { name: "light2", isOn: false },
      { name: "light3", isOn: false },
      { name: "light4", isOn: true },
      { name: "light5", isOn: true }
    ]
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  toggleLight = light => {
    return () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        lights: prevState.lights.map(_light => {
          return _light === light
            ? {
                ...light,
                isOn: !light.isOn
              }
            : _light;
        })
      }));
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { lights } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {lights.map(light => (
          <Islbutton
            key={light.name}
            name={light.name}
            isOn={light.isOn}
            toggleLight={this.toggleLight(light)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! <3